# How can Quartz configuration file (quartz.properties) pick up jobstore driver class dynamically depending on the type of database

Tags: web-applications, quartz-scheduler

I am using Quartz in my web application with the Jobstore as JDBC-JobStoreCMT and not the default RAMJobStore. My application will be using Mssql or Oracle database depending upon the customer. 
Each time I change the database from Oracle to Mssql or otherwise, I have to change the *driverDelegateClass* property value in the quartz.properties file. My quartz.properties file are like this

MSSQL -

```
# Default Properties file for use by StdSchedulerFactory
# to create a Quartz Scheduler Instance, if a different
# properties file is not explicitly specified.
#

org.quartz.scheduler.instanceName: DatabaseScheduler
org.quartz.scheduler.rmi.export: false
org.quartz.scheduler.rmi.proxy: false
org.quartz.scheduler.wrapJobExecutionInUserTransaction: false

org.quartz.threadPool.class: org.quartz.simpl.SimpleThreadPool
org.quartz.threadPool.threadCount: 5
org.quartz.threadPool.threadPriority: 5
org.quartz.threadPool.threadsInheritContextClassLoaderOfInitializingThread: true

org.quartz.jobStore.misfireThreshold: 60000


# Changes for JDBCJobStoreTX

org.quartz.jobStore.class = org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.JobStoreCMT
org.quartz.jobStore.driverDelegateClass = org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.MSSQLDelegate
org.quartz.jobStore.dataSource = quartzDataSource
org.quartz.jobStore.tablePrefix = QRTZ_
org.quartz.scheduler.skipUpdateCheck = true
org.quartz.scheduler.jobFactory.class = org.quartz.simpl.SimpleJobFactory
```

ORACLE-

```
org.quartz.scheduler.instanceName: NDFSScheduler
org.quartz.scheduler.rmi.export: false
org.quartz.scheduler.rmi.proxy: false
org.quartz.scheduler.wrapJobExecutionInUserTransaction: false

org.quartz.threadPool.class: org.quartz.simpl.SimpleThreadPool
org.quartz.threadPool.threadCount: 25
org.quartz.threadPool.threadPriority: 5
org.quartz.threadPool.threadsInheritContextClassLoaderOfInitializingThread: true

org.quartz.jobStore.misfireThreshold: 60000


# Changes for JDBCJobStoreTX

org.quartz.jobStore.class = org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.JobStoreCMT
org.quartz.jobStore.driverDelegateClass = org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.oracle.OracleDelegate
org.quartz.jobStore.dataSource = quartzDataSource
org.quartz.jobStore.tablePrefix = QRTZ_
org.quartz.scheduler.skipUpdateCheck = true
org.quartz.scheduler.jobFactory.class = org.quartz.simpl.SimpleJobFactory
```

Is there any way, that I need not do this setup and the quartz will automatically pick up the correct *driverDelegateClass* depending upon the Database. Or any way that this property (driverDelegateClass) is picked up from different file ?

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that you instantiate the Quartz scheduler instance programmatically in your code by using StdSchedulerFactory#getScheduler method, then you can use one of the following two StdSchedulerFactory constructors that allow you to pass a different set of properties (think quartz.properties).

```
StdSchedulerFactory(Properties props) 
StdSchedulerFactory(String fileName)
```

Note: fileName can be either a resource located on your application's classpath, or a file located outside of your application.

In your code you can easily switch between various DB profiles by picking a different quartz.properties file (e.g. quartz-mssql.properties, quqrtz-oracle.properties) based on your application's config.

If you are using Spring (i.e. the SchedulerFactoryBean class) to construct the Quartz scheduler instance, then you can use the PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer to achieve the same thing.